# Magento 2.3.4 Server Transfer - No homepage/admin Access Denied

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2.3.4, transfer

I decided to do a copy of my production server(2.3.4) to a local machine running Centos 8 for development testing.

Moved file/folders and did a database dump. Got everything to install and files/db installed. Manually changed URL in the database to the localhost IP. Made sure the env file had an updated DB connection.
Magento commands all run great.

Yet when I browse to the site I get "Access Denied". I also get this browsing to the admin URL.

Checking the apache log files I get the below error when try accessing the site.

> [Sun May 17 03:26:44.887007 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1557:tid 14 
>   0028793571072] [client 192.168.0.223:43658] AH01071: Got error 'Unabl 
>   e to open primary script: /var/www/html/index.php (Permission denied) 
>   \n'

I tried looking it up but have not found any reason that would cause this. I have TRIPLE CHECKED all permissions on every file/folder.
If I replace Index.php in my apache root folder I get a test site to show up fine.
My production site is hosted by Siteground, Is there a chance it also uses Nginx AND Apache? Not familiar with Nginx, but it is the only thing that pops up when I google the error. My production site used .htaccess files so I figured Nginx wasn't a thing on it.

[image]

**UPDATE:** Discovered SELinux security issues with files. Discovered this via trying to load Http:/(web address)/info.php and got the same access denied error.

When running `restorecon` on info.php it would now resolve! Thinking this is my issue I ran it on my web directory `var/www/html`. I no longer get the Access Denied error loading the page or in the Apache logs.

Sadly it did not fix my site. It now just loads a blank screen with no error. Also no error in the logs. Any one have any ideas why? Did I possibly mess up permission issues trying to fix the previous issues. Is there a way to output a error message?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2 and Answer: After getting the index.php to actually load although blank, I set it to display errors.

This lead me to see that zend cache couldn't write to the pub folder. Running `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t` on the directories got me up and running!

So, in the future fix SELinux issues when transferring servers!